# AWS Cloudwatch Metric and callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop do not work together?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, metrics

below is a simplification of my code.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');


exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true;

  AWS.config.update({region: 'cn-north-1'});

  // Create CloudWatch service object
  var cw = new AWS.CloudWatch({apiVersion: '2010-08-01'});

  var params = {
    MetricData: [
      {
        MetricName: 'PAGES_VISITED',
        Dimensions: [
          {
            Name: 'UNIQUE_PAGES',
            Value: 'URLS'
          },
        ],
        Unit: 'None',
        Value: 1.0
      },
    ],
    Namespace: 'MyNewNameSpace'
  };

  cw.putMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Success", JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });

  callback(null, "the result");
};
```

It seems that once I set the **callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false** then the metric cannot be put up there. I donot understand this conflict.

Comment: Two questions: (1) why are you trying to set `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` when your handler is an async function and should not be using the callback model (it should return a promise or await and return the response) and (2) why is your handler an async function `exports.handler = async (event,...`?  Perhaps in this case you should remove `async`?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` then your function execution terminates before all the callbacks are done. In this case, the function terminates before the callback from `cw.putMetricData` is ever called, so your code is not executed. It is likely that the operation on CloudWatch actually happens, but that you just don't see the callback, as it does not happen.

Here's your function, using the `async/await` model, without callbacks and without `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop`:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async event => {
  AWS.config.update({region: 'cn-north-1'});

  // Create CloudWatch service object
  var cw = new AWS.CloudWatch({apiVersion: '2010-08-01'});

  var params = {...};

  await cw.putMetricData(params)
    .promise()
    .then(data => {console.log("Success", JSON.stringify(data));})
    .catch(err => {console.log("Error", err);})

  return "the result";
};
```